# What pre-trained models are available?

Tags: neural-network, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

It's not entirely clear what pre-trained networks are out there in deep learning. Of particular interest to me are the deep convolutional networks.

I'm only aware of the VGG series like VGG16/VGG19. I searched the internet for Microsoft's famous ResNet that won ImageNet 2015, but couldn't find it. I suppose the corporate giants don't really share their models, eh?

Any pointers to maybe a comprehensive list that I have simply overlooked or there isn't one?

Comment: I don't think they share their trained models for complicated/large problems because a lot of time and energy (thus money) went into the creation of models. However google for example made a post on how to create Deepdream images, although you have to create the model yourself (https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb)